# purpose of argv and argc in opencv programs?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have just started learning opencv and i am stuck at the very first example of just loading an image.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  IplImage* imageName =cvLoadImage( argv[1]);
```

what task is argv  and argc carrying out?

Comment: since you're just starting, if you see any code that uses IplImages, that's outdated. use c++, cv::Mat, cv::imread() and such.

Comment: Actually i don't know c++ properly. I have knowledge of c only. Should i learn c++ now?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really about OpenCV.  This is a feature of the C language.

`argv` and `argc` are the parameters of the `main()` function, which allow your program to take command line arguments.  `argv` is an array of c-style strings, and `argc` is the number of strings in `argv`.  `argv[0]` is the name of your executable, and `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` are the command line arguments to your program.  In your example, `argv[1]` is the first command line argument, that contains the file name of the image to be loaded.

Let's say the name of your executable is `myOpencvProgram`. If you invoke it from the command line like this:

```
> myOpencvProgram image1.jpg
```

then `argv[0]` will contain the string `"myOpencvProgram"`, `argv[1]` will contain `"image1.jpg"`, and `argc` will be equal to 2.